# Home network shares are not accessible when Internet is down

Tags: networking, home-networking

I have this problem at home. When I loose internet connection, I am unable to access shared folders from one PC to another. here is my topology.

```
  ++
                                || <---------+ INTERNET
                                ||
                         +------vv------+
                         |              |
                         |  ROUTER      +
                         |              |
                         +--------------|        +------------+
                                        |        |            |
                                        +-------+|  RAS-PI    |
         WiFi                              ^     |            |
          +------>  ^   +                  |     +------+-----+
                    |   |                  +            |
                    |   |            ethernet           |     +--------+
                    +   v                               |     |        |
         +---------------+                              |     |--------|
         |               |                              +-----+ USB-HDD|
         | WIN PC(//share)                                    |        |
         |               |                                    +--------+
         +---------------+
```

Is this accepted behaviour with home network or should I have some specific network configuration to ensure even if I do not have internet connecion the devices inside the network should be able to talk to each other.

Thanks in advance for the help.
./b.

Comment: Do you have a DNS server, or is your router acting as a DNS relay? I'm wondering if your Internet connection is actually offline when you experience problems, and instead it is a issue with a service used for both internal and external access.

Comment: No, I don't have a seperate DNS server. I experience problems only when my internet is offline. What is mean is, I am not able to access any public sites from an home pc. When this happens, share folders across devices are not accessible.

Comment: What I think Frank Thomas is getting at is that this might not be an issue with your Internet, it might be your router going offline or having other issues.  This would cause both a loss of Internet, and a loss of connectivity to internal resources.

Comment: Oh okay. So is there a way I can fix this. I use [Belking N750](http://www.cnet.com/products/belkin-n750-db-wireless-dual-band-n-plus-router/) as my router.

Comment: Do you access your shares by name, or by IP address? This is what @FrankThomas asked.

Comment: I use IP address to access shares.

Comment: When your Internet is down, try pinging the other addresses in your network. If you can ping them when the Internet is up, but can't when it's down, then it would strongly point to the issue being with your router.

Comment: I cannot ping them when the internet is down, so looks like an issue with the router. is this just with my router or do all home routers work this way?

Comment: well, based on your diagram, your router is acting as your LAN switch, and as such, if it is starting to die, or is otherwise experiencing an issue, then yes, you would not be able to connect to other devices connected to the router.

Comment: @FrankThomas, thank you. But what should I be doing to keep my home devices accessible from each other?

Comment: well, the first step is to confirm the problem. next time you have an issue, reboot the router, either from the webconsole or by powercycling it. if the web console is not available, that makes it all the more likely that the issue is the router. if when it comes back up, everything works fine, then the router is dying, and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your devices with Static IP addressess.
Use the router's IP address as the gateway AND the Preferred DNS server.
You don't need a seconday DNS server because if you don't have access to your own router, you won't have access to anywhere else either!
Here are another 1000 words:
[image: Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) Properties with a static IP address]

Comment: while a static IP address might solve a discoverability issue, if the op can't ping by a known IP  (static or dynamic) then setting a static IP can't be the whole fix.

Comment: WIth the IP set to static, it will be known.No matter what.